# Is there a way to report an offensive pseudonym?

Tags: support

This user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6031666/bite-catholique?tab=profile created a trolling question which was immediately deleted.

But his pseudonym means "Catholic d*ck" in French. In this case, it is obvious this account is only for trolling. Is there a way to report such a user?

Comment: See [Flag abusive users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1323/310998) and [Possibly offensive usernames](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117596/310998).

Comment: Thanks for answers. So it is not possible to directly report an username.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the user hasn't made any posts or all their posts are deleted and inaccessible to you, flag one of your own posts with a custom flag and explain clearly what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

> But his pseudo means in French "Catholic d*ck". In this case, it is
>   obvious this account is only for trolling. Is it a way to report such
>   an user ?

There is! Flag one of the user's posts as "needs moderator attention" and explain in the custom flag text.